# Is there any existing hash algorithm that is given a string and returns an integer?

Tags: encryption, hash

Is there a hashing algorithm that is given a string such as `Mike` for example, and then returns an integer such as `55936782`.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do

```
John == 37935291
Mike == 55936782
AoihsY8G87HKIW == 15834408
```

Comment: Depends on how you define "integer". Every hash function just returns a bunch of bits (some less, some more) how you interpret those bits is completely up to you. If you mean a hash function  which returns quite a short hash value, you may find a suitable one here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions

Comment: Well, it seems that you are able to convert strings to integers, then it might not hard to do convert byte[] to integer, too, though it will be too long for a standard integer. Why do you want to convert integer rather than hex or Base64?